# How to schedule tasks recursively using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Can I somehow use `ExecutorService` in Java in order to schedule recursive tasks?

**Example code:** (Note: try/catch around Thread.sleep omitted for enhanced readability)

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    executor.execute(() -> { // TASK 1
        Thread.sleep(100); // simulate some work

        executor.execute(() -> { // TASK2
            Thread.sleep(500); // simulate some longer work
        });

    });
}

# terminate when all tasks proceeded
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(9999999, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

**Problem seems to be the order of execution:**

1. create executor
2. schedule execution of TASK 1 (8x)
3. shutdown
4. awaitTermination
5. end of first sleep, then schedule execution of TASK 2
6. FAIL, because after shutdown no task may be executed.

This is, I believe, common problem. However, I can't find any suitable solution. List of what I seek:

**Requirements:**

- ability to exectute tasks from already scheduled tasks
- block somehow at the end until all tasks are completed
- no active waiting for tasks execution
- fixed max. number of threads used
- possibly lock-free and thread-safe

Could you please help me? I don't feel like implementing my own thread pool as this must be already implemented manytimes (preferably in standard library).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your core problem is that the some tasks may or may not spawn more tasks sometime during their run time. You must therefore wait for at least that task to complete before shutting down. You cannot use the `executor.shutdown()` or you will certainly close the pool prematurely.

You must implement some mechanism to choreograph which tasks must wait for another to complete and you must maintain a list of all tasks that must complete before shutdown of the pool.

Here's a rudimentary demonstration of what you will need to do. You will probably need something more sophisticated depending on the interrelation requirements of your tasks.

Essentially, use `Callable`s and `Future<Void>.get()` to wait for any task that must complete.

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

class Task1 implements Callable<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(100); // simulate some work
        return null;
    }

}

class Task2 implements Callable<Void> {

    final Future<Void> waitFor;

    Task2(Future<Void> waitFor) {
        // This task must wait for a previous task to complete before commencement.
        this.waitFor = waitFor;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // Wait for the first task to complete.
        waitFor.get();
        Thread.sleep(100); // simulate some work
        return null;
    }

}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    // All of these tasks must complete before we close down the pool.
    List<Future<Void>> waitFor = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Future<Void> f1 = executor.submit(new Task1());
        // We must wait for f1 to complete.
        waitFor.add(f1);
        // No need to wait for f2.
        executor.submit(new Task2(f1));
    }
    // Wait for all of the primary tasks to complete.
    for (Future<Void> wait : waitFor) {
        try {
            wait.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    // Can now shut down - will wait for all sub-tasks to complete because they are all in the queue now.
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(9999999, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice solution, however, I'd rather avoid forcing the user to implement their own dependency management. Moreover, the number of tasks etc. isn't known (as they may be given via network). I'm rather looking for simple solution for the user i.e. using only lambdas (not some complicated classes with dependencies). Maybe your solution could be transformed that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` based on `PriorityBlockingQueue`. Then you put shutDownTask to the end of `Queue` which will wait complete of others and then shutDown pool. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestExec {

    public static void main(String... s){

        PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(10,
                (o1,o2)-> {return o1 instanceof MyRunnable ? 1 : (o2 instanceof MyRunnable ? -1 : 0);} // shutDownTask at bottom of queue
                );
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      queue);

        //recursive tasks
        Runnable task3 = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println("done task 3");
        };
        Runnable task2 = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            executor.execute(task3);
            System.out.println("done task 2");
        };
        Runnable task1 = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            executor.execute(task2);
            System.out.println("done task 1");
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            executor.execute(task1);
        }

        //shutDownTask
        MyRunnable r = ()->{
            while(executor.getActiveCount() > 1){ //wait until other tasks to be done
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            executor.shutdown();
            try {
                executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }};
        executor.execute(r);
    }

    private static interface MyRunnable extends Runnable{
        // dummy Runnable
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution contains active waiting (shutDownTask definition) which is unacceptable. However, the idea of extra shutting task seems legit. Unfortunately I can't develop the idea. Are we really sure that it's going to be executed as the last one?

Comment: Here `while(executor.getActiveCount() > 1)` is condition for active waiting if in some case pool will have just shutDownTask in queue and one executing task which can run a new one task. Before that condition `executer` gets real tasks from pool and execute them.

Comment: In other words active waiting starts when pool have tasks in queue less then number of pool threads.

Comment: Does Executor preserve the order of the tasks? I can't see this information anywhere in documentation.

Comment: Executor gets tasks from `queue`, in our case `queue` is [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) which guarantee order.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use the [afterExecute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) method and change the behavior of the `shutdown` method. Here is a small runnable demo program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TpShutdownAfterTasksDone extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private volatile boolean shutdown;
    private final CountDownLatch preShutdown = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public TpShutdownAfterTasksDone() {
        this(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
        // Copied from
        // Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    public TpShutdownAfterTasksDone(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {

        shutdown = true;
        if (getActiveCount() < 1 && getQueue().size() < 1) {
            println("Immediate shutdown");
            realShutdown();
        }
    }

    protected void realShutdown() {

        println("Real shutdown");
        super.shutdown();
        preShutdown.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {

        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (shutdown && getActiveCount() <= 1 && getQueue().size() < 1) {
            // see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21277746/3080094
            // active count is still 1 when this method is executed after the last task.
            println("AfterExecute shutdown");
            realShutdown();
        } else {
            println("Tasks: " + getActiveCount());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {

        if (!preShutdown.await(timeout, unit)) {
            return false;
        }
        // TODO: calculate remaining timeout period
        return super.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadPoolExecutor tp = new TpShutdownAfterTasksDone();
        try {
            println("Executing test runnable.");
            tp.execute(new TestRunRunnable(tp));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            println("Shutting tp down.");
            tp.shutdown();
            try { 
                println("Awaiting tp termination.");
                if (tp.awaitTermination(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    println("Tp terminated.");
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Tp did not terminate.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tp.shutdownNow();
            }
        }

    }

    static class TestRunRunnable implements Runnable {

        ThreadPoolExecutor tp;
        public TestRunRunnable(ThreadPoolExecutor tp) {
            this.tp = tp;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

            sleep(100);
            tp.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sleep(500);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static void sleep(int time) {

        try {
            println("Sleeping " + time);
            Thread.sleep(time);
            println("Slept " + time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final long START_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    private static void println(String msg) {
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - START_TIME) + "\t " + msg);
    }

}
```

Output is something like:

```
2    Executing test runnable.
3    Shutting tp down.
3    Sleeping 100
3    Awaiting tp termination.
103  Slept 100
103  Tasks: 2
104  Sleeping 500
604  Slept 500
604  AfterExecute shutdown
604  Real shutdown
604  Tp terminated.
```